# How to create right-to-left TOC using OpenXML

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have created a *TOC* for my `DOCX` file using `C#` and `OpenXML` using [this tutorial](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/08/08/exploring-tables-of-contents-in-open-xml-wordprocessingml-documents.aspx). The problem is I cannot manage list of my *TOC* to get *right-to-left*. I was able to change to change sample XML to make *TOC*'s header *RtL*. But it seems nothing can change the list items. Here is the changed XML I'm using:

```
<w:sdt xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'>

  <w:sdtPr>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:jc w:val='right'/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme='minorHAnsi' w:eastAsiaTheme='minorHAnsi' w:hAnsiTheme='minorHAnsi'/>
      <w:bCs w:val='0'/>
      <w:i w:val='0'/>
      <w:color w:val='auto'/>
      <w:sz w:val='22'/>
      <w:szCs w:val='22'/>
      <w:rtl/>
      <w:lang w:eastAsia='en-US' w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:docPartObj>
      <w:docPartGallery w:val='Table of Contents'/>
      <w:docPartUnique/>
    </w:docPartObj>
  </w:sdtPr>

  <w:sdtEndPr>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:jc w:val='right'/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme='minorHAnsi' w:cstheme='minorBidi' w:eastAsiaTheme='minorHAnsi' w:hAnsiTheme='minorHAnsi'/>
      <w:color w:val='auto'/>
      <w:sz w:val='22'/>
      <w:szCs w:val='22'/>
      <w:rFonts w:cstheme='minorBidi'/>
      <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
      <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:sdtEndPr>

  <w:sdtContent>

    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line='50' w:lineRule='auto'/>
        <w:jc w:val='right'/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:eastAsia='en-US' w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>
          <!-- empty parag -->
        </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val='TOCHeading'/>
        <w:spacing w:line='500' w:lineRule='auto'/>
        <w:jc w:val='right'/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>{0}</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val='TOC1'/>
        <w:jc w:val='right' />
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:eastAsiaTheme='minorEastAsia' w:cstheme='minorBidi' w:hint='cs'/>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val='left' w:leader='dot' w:pos='{1}'/>
        </w:tabs>
      </w:pPr>

      <w:jc w:val='right' />
      <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR' />

      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii='Lucida Console'/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:sz w:val='24'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='begin'/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii='Lucida Console'/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:sz w:val='24'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space='preserve'> {2} </w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii='Lucida Console'/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:sz w:val='24'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='separate'/>
      </w:r>

    </w:p>

    <w:p>

      <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val='right' />
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>

      <w:jc w:val='right' />
      <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR' />

      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:bCs/>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii='Lucida Console'/>
          <w:i/>
          <w:sz w:val='24'/>
          <w:rtl w:val='1'/>
          <w:lang w:bidi='fa-IR'/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='end'/>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

I almost tried every property on every node! But nothing changed. Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "Right-to-left", you want to display the toc from right to left ?
Do you try to do it directly with word ? The simplest way is to do it in real then take a look at xml code word create.
it seems possible to set page numbers on left.. I take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove spaces and return in your file with regex?  I tested with small piece of your xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<w:sdt xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'>\n" +
                  "<w:sdtPr>\n" +
                    "<w:pPr>\n" +
                      "<w:jc w:val='right'/>\n" +
                    "</w:pPr>\n" +
                    "<w:rPr>\n" +
                      "<w:rFonts w:asciiTheme='minorHAnsi' w:eastAsiaTheme='minorHAnsi' w:hAnsiTheme='minorHAnsi'/>\n" +
                      "<w:bCs w:val='0'/>\n" +
                      "<w:i w:val='0'/>\n" +
                      "<w:color w:val='auto'/>\n";

            //remove spaces at beginning of line
            string pattern1 = @"^\s+<";
            input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern1, "<");
            //remove spaces and return at end of line
            string pattern2 = ">\\s*\n";
            input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern2, ">",RegexOptions.Singleline);

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: editing manually openxml is awful, I don't recommand to do it.
And spaces have no incidence in openxml, so it won't solve a thing

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to use "Bidi" inside your paragraph (such a cute name).
If you manually create a word with a "right to left" TOC and look at a differences inside the xml you'll notice only one tag is added

```
<w:p w:rsidP="00A63AAE" w:rsidRDefault="00A63AAE" w:rsidR="000E5A53">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="TM2"/>
    <w:bidi/>
```

So, on each paragraphProperties of your TOC, do a pPr.Append(new BiDi()) and it should do the work.

To have access to bidirection in Word, you have to add a Language (like Arabic) that use bidirection. Maybe you'll have to add a language like this in your word to enable the use of Bidi (there is a chance word delete bidi tag after a save if it don't find a bidirectional language in the word setting)